# How to setInterval and clearInterval on the same DOM object with .click?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

**BLUF**:  I'm attempting to add a function that will dynamically convert a time element from 24h to 12h format and vice versa. The date and time objects all work as intended, however I'm in a bit over my head and I can't figure out add this functionality.

**BACKGROUND**:  I'm trying to replace the time format (12/24h) when a `.click` event is fired. I've got it mostly working, however I can't seem to figure out how to stop one function and start another using the same selector so that the user can swap back and forth between time formats without having to refresh the DOM.

**ISSUE**: Using the code below when the `TIME` DIV is clicked it will convert the time to 12h (`setTime12`) format, but when the same selector is clicked to convert back to 24h (`setTime24`), the 'TIME' element transitions back and forth between the 12 and 24 hour formats every second. Obviously, this is because `clearInterval` is not being applied properly so both of the functions are executing simultaneously.

**So how do I dynamically trigger the `setTime12` & `setTime24` functions ensuring they are not executing at the same time?**

CHEERS!

Here is a GIF to illustrate the issue:

[image: homepage_interval_gif]

- The project I'm working on is hosted here: https://github.com/seanvree/homepage
- The features I'm adding to the above project are in the develop branch: https://github.com/seanvree/homepage/tree/develop
- The main .JS file is here:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seanvree/homepage/develop/js/main.js
- Working DEMO (without this feature added): https://seanvree.github.io/homepage/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="timeArea">
    <p class="time" id="time" data-switch="b">
        <span id="hours"></span><span id="colon">:</span><span id="minutes"></span>
        <span class="date"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function setTime24() {
    var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
        hour12: false,
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
    });
    var parts = d.split(":");
    $('#hours').text(parts[0]);
    $('#minutes').text(parts[1]);
    $("#colon").css({
        visibility: toggle ? "visible" : "hidden"
    });
    toggle = !toggle;
};

function setTime12() {
    var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
        hour12: true,
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
    });
    var parts = d.split(":");
    $('#hours').text(parts[0]);
    $('#minutes').text(parts[1]);
    $("#colon").css({
        visibility: toggle ? "visible" : "hidden"
    });
    toggle = !toggle;
};

setDate($);

$('#time').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);
    switch (that.data('switch')) {
        case 'a':
            console.log('Set Time to 24h');
            $('#time').removeClass('12hr');
            $('#time').addClass('24hr');
            var myVar24 = setInterval(setTime24, 1000);
            clearInterval(myVar12);
            that.data('switch', 'b');
            break;
        case 'b':
            console.log('Set Time to 12h');
            $('#time').removeClass('24hr');
            $('#time').addClass('12hr');
            setTime12()
            var myVar12 = setInterval(setTime12, 1000);
            clearInterval(myVar24);
            that.data('switch', 'a');
            break;
    };
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken on account of the use of JQ here, `var myVar12 = setInterval(setTime12, 1000);` no longer exists the next time you enter the case statement. If you'd like to access this variable, make it a global or attach it to some object. As it stands, it's just a lonely (almost immediately lost/destroyed) variable that holds the reference to the interval timer.

Comment: @enhzflep thanks for your response. It is defined in HEAD.  I've tried to attach it to another element, but the same behavior occurs.

Comment: the variable I'm talking about (and copy/pasted) is defined within one of the case blocks of a switch statement. Doesn't matter if _that_ code is in the head or elsewhere, point is - the variable should not have a lifetime defined by the start and conclusion of a single function. The variable should live for the whole time the application does.

Comment: @enhzflep I guess my noobness is getting the better of me...looks like I'll have to research what you said and try something new, I'm obviously a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `var myVar12, myVar24;` in the line above `$('#time').click(function (e) {` and remove the `var` declaration inside the switch cases.

Comment: YES! This was it.  Thank you, SIr.